# How can I get all saved results from Assert.Multiple in a catch-block?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

```
[Test]
public void AssertMultipleTest()
{
    try
    {
        Assert.Multiple(() =>
        {
            Assert.That(true, Is.False);
            Assert.That(7, Is.Zero);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Save(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

The test function generates the following report:

```
  One or more failures in Multiple Assert block:
  1)   Expected: False
  But was:  True

  2)   Expected: 0
  But was:  7
```

How can I get the same report in the catch-block? Now I only get the following:

```
Tests.AssertMultipleTest - NUnit.Framework.MultipleAssertException: One or more failures in Multiple Assert block:
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Multiple(TestDelegate testDelegate)
   at AnonymizeDataTests.Tests.AssertMultipleTest() in C:\Development\TestClass.cs:line 76
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found a solution to my problem. Instead of logging the error in the test itself I skip the entire try-catch-block and log the result in TearDown instead. Something like this:

```
    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status != TestStatus.Passed)
        {
            Log.Save(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void AssertMultipleTest()
    {
        Assert.Multiple(() =>
        {
            Assert.That(true, Is.False);
            Assert.That(7, Is.Zero);
        });
    }
```